# Can i send a variable along with xmlhttp response text?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a function defined like this:

```
function call_view_details(viewid)
{
    view_details(viewid);
    setInterval(function(){view_details(viewid)},5000);
}
```

which i call at page load. Mainly it sets interval for `view_details()`.

Here's `view_details()`:

```
function view_details(viewid)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("item_details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;         
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","view_item.php?id="+viewid,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, `view_details()` updates some `div` with `view_item.php`'s response.

But i want on some cases (which happen in `view_item.php`), to execute `clearInterval()` on `view_details()`.

Now i don't want to say:

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText==/*something*/)
    /*clearInterval*/
```

That's because, first, there are a lot of cases, and second, also in those cases `view_item.php` echos something i need to update the `div` with.

So maybe i can let `view_item.php` pass some variable in addition to its response? And then i can make a condition on that variable.

I hope it's clear enough...

Thank you

Comment: just pass it upfront and let closure connect the dots: function view_details(viewid, interval)... and call like var myInterval=setInterval(function(){view_details(viewid, myInterval)},5000); you can then clearInteval(interval); inside the ajax callback when/if needed.

Comment: You mean let `view_item.php` call `view_details()` with a variable after it echos what i want?

Comment: you can do clearInteval(interval) in view_details() or in onreadystatechange(); dealer's choice...

Comment: i know. but that's not the question. The question is how will `view_details()` know it's time for `clearInterval()`

Comment: return a JSON object with a boolean variable when you need to call `clearInterval`.

Comment: ahh, i getcha now. you could return a 203 status (the forgotten 20x) for one and a 200 for the other. that would be explicit in your callback and easy to rig in php without refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a JSON object.

view_item.php

```
<?php

  // PHP stuff

$returnArray = array();

$returnArray['message'] = $yourRespondText;

$returnArray['clearInterval'] = true; // return true when you want to call clearInterval


echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

JS:

```
function call_view_details(viewid)
{
    view_details(viewid);
    var interval = setInterval(function(){view_details(viewid, interval )},5000);
}




function view_details(viewid, yourInterval)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            if(data.clearInterval) {
                clearInterval(yourInterval);
            }
            document.getElementById("item_details").innerHTML=data.message;         
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","view_item.php?id="+viewid,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. For now, @dandavis's solution worked just fine. But i will definitely try this as well. Thanks

Comment: i tried it and i get an error message `Unexpected token <` on line 15 (`data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);`). That's maybe because my output includes a `<` in the beginning? Is something wrong with this?

Comment: i had a error in the PHP section replace `return` by `echo json_encode($returnArray);` also when you have error with ajax call, looking the network tab in the browser console helps a lot.

Comment: i still have the same error. and i do look the network tab... it says it called `view_item.php` with the correct id. and status code: 200 (OK).

Comment: ok looks like the error was that i still was `echo`ing some text in `view_item.php`. i solved it by creating more elements in the array corresponding to my output. Eventually it worked great! Thank you!
I'll choose this answer because i think it's more professional.

Comment: 1 question though. I've been using this line `xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` without ever understanding it. What is `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` ? Is it related to the `xmlhttp` variable i defined in the beginning? Namely if i define `xmlhttp1` instead, should i write `xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP1");` ?

Comment: No, it's ok like this, old Internet Explorer version use ActiveXObject. Documentation could help you understand it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.